# Pass a variable from controller to html in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cordova

index.html

```
<div class="center" ng-controller="DescriptionController">
<p>{{perigrafi}}</p></div>
```

app.js

```
 app.controller('DescriptionController', function($scope, dataPassingService) {

    $scope.description = dataPassingService.get();
    var perigrafi = $scope.description.Description_en;
    var onoma = $scope.description.Name_en;
    alert("the description is " + perigrafi);
});
```

The datapassing service is function that passing data between controllers.The alert work perfect but when I try to show the perigrafi in html file is not work any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well you can directly use $scope.description object in your html without creating new unnecessary variable

```
$scope.description.Description_en // for var perigrafi

$scope.description.Name_en; //  for var onoma
```

and in HTML you can do like this

```
<p>{{description.Description_en}}</p>
<p>{{description.Name_en}}</p>
```

Comment: The question is not about wether he can use it directly or not. Its about why is it not getting binded.

Answer (score 2):

perigrafi must be in `$scope` in your case like `$scope.perigrafi`

```
app.controller('DescriptionController', function($scope, dataPassingService){
    $scope.description = dataPassingService.get();
    $scope.perigrafi = $scope.description.Description_en;
    var onoma = $scope.description.Name_en;
    alert("the description is " + perigrafi);
});
```

Comment: @AntonisKountouretis glad to help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Angular.js two way binding for variables work only for those variables which are defined over scope. Since you have defined `perigrafi` as a `local variable`, therefore it is not getting binded into html as you are expecting. Put your variable perigrafi on `$scope` as `$scope.perigrafi` as suggested by @rkalita.

```
app.controller('DescriptionController', function($scope, dataPassingService) {
  $scope.description = dataPassingService.get();
  $scope.perigrafi = $scope.description.Description_en;
  var onoma = $scope.description.Name_en;
  alert("the description is " + $scope.perigrafi);
});
```